# Setting Up UDP C# code

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am very new to sockets with C# and I have been working on trying to get a socket to work with localhost. Here is the main UDP code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class NetUDP
        {
             private UdpClient udp;
             private IPEndPoint endPont;

        public NetUDP(int port_local, int port_global, string ip_global, string ip_local)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(IPAddress.Any.ToString());
            udp = new UdpClient(IPAddress.Any.ToString(), port_global);
            endPont = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip_global), port_global);
            udp.Connect(ip_global, port_global);
        }

        public NetUDP()
        {

        }


        public void UDPinit(int port_local, int port_global, string ip_global, string ip_local)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            udp = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1", port_global);
            endPont = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port_global);
            udp.Connect("127.0.0.1", port_global);
        }

        public void sendDataUDP(string info)
        {
            Byte[] SendByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(info);
            udp.Send(SendByte, SendByte.Length);
        }

        public string getDataUDP()
        {
            Byte[] get = udp.Receive(ref endPont);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(get);
        }

        public void closeUDP()
        {
           udp.Close();
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem is every time I do this code when I try to retrieve info from another UDP C# program (on the same machine) it freezes. I know it keeps on looking for info coming it's way, but id there a way to put a timeout on the receive command or do I have to make an event handler to prevent this freezing? The ports connect just fine and do not show any form of error or exception. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8500);
        NetUDP udp = new NetUDP(serverEndPoint);


        UdpClient localClient = new UdpClient();

        Task.Delay(20000);
        var dgram = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello Server");
        localClient.Send(dgram, dgram.Length, serverEndPoint);  // Send "Hello Server" to Server

        Console.Read();
    }
}

class NetUDP
{
    private UdpClient udp;
    private IPEndPoint endPont;

    public NetUDP() { }
    public NetUDP(IPEndPoint serverEndPoint)
    {
        udp = new UdpClient(serverEndPoint);  // Bind the EndPoint

        // Receive any IPAddress send to the 8555 port
        IPEndPoint receiveEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8555);

        Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        // This Receive will block until receive an UdpClient
                        // So, run in another thread in thread pool
                        var bytes = udp.Receive(ref receiveEndPoint);
                        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // TODO
                }
                finally
                {
                    udp.Close();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Here is and UdpChat demo in github: [UdpChat](https://github.com/KanLei/UdpAndTcp)